# Loading all Angular controllers, filters, directives, and services

Tags: angularjs

I've scaffolded my Laravel/Angular app and have an `app/` directory in `project/public/assets/`

Inside of the app directory I have an `app.js` file, and directories for `controllers/`, `filters/`, etc.

Rather than loading each individual controller, filter, etc.. how can I load all of them in the directory?

Comment: If I understand you right you want to load all files at the same time instead of loading each seperate file? If thats the case you need to concatinate them. I usually use Gruntjs to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, as @cbass rightly said you should concatenate them. Its recommended to concat it for production build, however you can try using this following structure to experiment

```
(function () {
  angular.module('app', []);

  // MainCtrl.js
  function MainCtrl () {

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  // AnotherCtrl.js
  function AnotherCtrl () {

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('AnotherCtrl', AnotherCtrl);

  // and so on...

})();
```

About code snippet referred from [Todd Motto's blog](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/)